# A Unicode Maven ArtifactId

Tags: maven-2, unicode

I just tried creating a project in Maven whose artifactId is made up entirely of non-English characters ("日本国").

I get the following feedback from Maven:

```
ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: com.worldevolved:日本国
POM Location: /tmp/日本国910145040748591900/pom.xml
Validation Messages:

    [0]  'artifactId' with value '日本国' does not match a valid id pattern.
```

Is there anything I can do to my POM file to get Maven to read the artifactId as is? Or does Maven not support Unicode characters in the artifactId?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No it doesn't support. According [DefaultModelValidator](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/maven-2/branches/maven-2.2.x/maven-project/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/project/validation/DefaultModelValidator.java) class 'artifactId' and 'groupId' have to match following regular expression

```
ID_REGEX = "[A-Za-z0-9_\\-.]+"
```

If you are intrested in other validations of maven pom file, looking into this class source code will be helpful.