# Cannot resolve symbol, but the dependency is in local repo

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I've been reading all similar problems with maven but I cannot seem to be able to fix it. The issue is the classic "Cannot resolve symbol 'pippo'", in which case pippo is part of

`import com.pippo.device.manager.data.model.Device;`

This class Device comes from this artifact that I have in my local repo

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.pippo</groupId>
    <artifactId>device.manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Evidence that it is in the local repository

```
/mnt/c/Users/sanvegeta/.m2/repository$ find . -type f -name "*device.manager*" -ls
38228 -rwxrwxrwx   1 sanvegeta sanvegeta 39142700 Oct  1 09:00 ./com/pippo/device.manager/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/device.manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    4 -rwxrwxrwx   1 sanvegeta sanvegeta     1969 Oct  1 08:47 ./com/pippo/device.manager/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/device.manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

and evidence that this is the correct local repository

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=settings.localRepository | grep -v '\[INFO\]'
/mnt/c/Users/sanvegeta/.m2/repository
```

Just to give you a little bit of context: I'm working on a lab exercise and I created 2 microservices: com.pluto.user.manager and com.pippo.device.manager. They both expose CRUD REST API to work respectively on User and Device. **Part of my exercise is to refer to the entity Device from another service** (in this case from com.pluto.user.manager) so, in the user.manager, I created an API that is supposed to link the device to the user (it's just adding an id to the user, nothing serious). And the compiler complains. I even tried to create a docker container with jdk, maven and git, and tried to compile there: same problem.

The class where the error appears is the following

```
package com.pluto.user.manager.controller;

import com.pippo.device.manager.data.model.Device; // problem here
import com.pluto.user.manager.data.model.User;
import com.pluto.user.manager.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    //  various CRUD API here
    //  ...

    @PostMapping(path = "/{id}/link",  consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public User link(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody Device device) {
        return userService.linkToDevice(id, device.getId());
    }
}
```

Please, can you help me understand what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1**: adding pom.xml of user.manager as requested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.pluto</groupId>
    <artifactId>user.manager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user.manager</name>
    <description>User Manager Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pippo</groupId>
            <artifactId>device.manager</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and the output of "mvn clean package"

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building user.manager 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ user.manager ---
[INFO] Deleting /mnt/e/Repository/GCP/exercise1/user.manager/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ user.manager ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ user.manager ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /mnt/e/Repository/GCP/exercise1/user.manager/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /mnt/e/Repository/GCP/exercise1/user.manager/src/main/java/com/pluto/user/manager/controller/UserController.java:[3,43] package com.pippo.device.manager.data.model does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/e/Repository/GCP/exercise1/user.manager/src/main/java/com/pluto/user/manager/controller/UserController.java:[40,99] package com.pippo.device.manager.data.model does not exist
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 37.983 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-10-01T23:01:35+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/100M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project user.manager: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /mnt/e/Repository/GCP/exercise1/user.manager/src/main/java/com/pluto/user/manager/controller/UserController.java:[3,43] package com.pippo.device.manager.data.model does not exist
[ERROR] /mnt/e/Repository/GCP/exercise1/user.manager/src/main/java/com/pluto/user/manager/controller/UserController.java:[40,99] package com.pippo.device.manager.data.model does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

and output of `jar -tvf /mnt/c/Users/sanvegeta/.m2/repository/com/pippo/device.manager/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/device.manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

```
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:58 CEST 2021 META-INF/
   467 Fri Oct 01 08:59:58 CEST 2021 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/
  5871 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/ClassPathIndexFile.class
  6806 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
  3966 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/JarLauncher.class
  1483 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$DefinePackageCallType.class
  1535 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.class
 11154 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
  5932 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/Launcher.class
  1536 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/MainMethodRunner.class
   266 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$1.class
  1484 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
  8128 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$ClassPathArchives.class
  1953 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
 18267 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/PropertiesLauncher.class
  1750 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/WarLauncher.class
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/
   302 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$Entry.class
   511 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive$EntryFilter.class
  4745 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/Archive.class
  6093 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$AbstractIterator.class
  2180 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$ArchiveIterator.class
  1857 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$EntryIterator.class
  1269 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
  2527 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive$SimpleJarFileArchive.class
  5346 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/ExplodedArchive.class
  2884 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$AbstractIterator.class
  1981 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.class
  1081 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class
  2528 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive$NestedArchiveIterator.class
 10349 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/archive/JarFileArchive.class
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/
   485 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessData.class
   282 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$1.class
  2680 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
  3259 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.class
  4015 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/data/RandomAccessDataFile.class
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/
  1438 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AbstractJarFile$JarFileType.class
   878 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AbstractJarFile.class
  4976 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/AsciiBytes.class
   616 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Bytes.class
   295 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$1.class
  3319 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$Zip64End.class
  2039 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord$Zip64Locator.class
  5029 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
  6889 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryFileHeader.class
  4624 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryParser.class
   540 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/CentralDirectoryVisitor.class
   345 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/FileHeader.class
 13649 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/Handler.class
  3885 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntry.class
  1458 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryCertification.class
   299 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarEntryFilter.class
  2299 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$1.class
  1299 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile$JarEntryEnumeration.class
 16312 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFile.class
  1368 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$1.class
  2258 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.class
  1281 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$Offsets.class
  1338 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$Zip64Offsets.class
  1334 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries$ZipOffsets.class
 17280 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileEntries.class
  3512 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarFileWrapper.class
   702 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$1.class
  4302 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
  9440 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/JarURLConnection.class
  3559 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/StringSequence.class
  1813 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jar/ZipInflaterInputStream.class
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/
   293 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarMode.class
  2201 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/JarModeLauncher.class
  1292 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/jarmode/TestJarMode.class
     0 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/
  5174 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 org/springframework/boot/loader/util/SystemPropertyUtils.class
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:58 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:58 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/controller/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/data/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/data/model/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/repository/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/service/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:56 CEST 2021 META-INF/maven/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:56 CEST 2021 META-INF/maven/com.pippo/
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:56 CEST 2021 META-INF/maven/com.pippo/device.manager/
   804 Fri Oct 01 08:59:36 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/application.properties
   737 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/Application.class
  2433 Fri Oct 01 08:59:48 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/controller/DeviceController.class
  1617 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/data/model/Device.class
   364 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/repository/DeviceRepository.class
  3530 Fri Oct 01 08:59:46 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/service/DeviceService.class
  1969 Fri Oct 01 08:47:32 CEST 2021 META-INF/maven/com.pippo/device.manager/pom.xml
    67 Fri Oct 01 08:59:56 CEST 2021 META-INF/maven/com.pippo/device.manager/pom.properties
     0 Fri Oct 01 08:59:58 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/
382204 Wed Sep 15 07:22:06 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aop-5.3.10.jar
2087074 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 BOOT-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.9.7.jar
159222 Wed Mar 03 13:06:58 CET 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/HikariCP-4.0.3.jar
427946 Wed Sep 15 07:22:12 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-5.3.10.jar
 15392 Fri Aug 02 22:14:54 CEST 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.transaction-api-1.3.3.jar
164392 Fri Aug 02 16:59:46 CEST 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.persistence-api-2.2.3.jar
7351256 Mon May 24 12:01:22 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar
 60911 Tue May 25 13:11:32 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jboss-logging-3.4.2.Final.jar
782774 Thu Mar 19 13:33:58 CET 2020 BOOT-INF/lib/javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar
3510658 Tue Mar 09 15:35:56 CET 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/byte-buddy-1.10.22.jar
445288 Wed Sep 06 11:15:04 CEST 2006 BOOT-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
202552 Fri Jan 22 15:15:02 CET 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jandex-2.2.3.Final.jar
 67815 Sat Oct 19 22:46:30 CEST 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/classmate-1.5.1.jar
323630 Sun Apr 12 12:05:40 CEST 2020 BOOT-INF/lib/dom4j-2.1.3.jar
 78948 Fri Oct 30 16:06:46 CET 2020 BOOT-INF/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.1.2.Final.jar
1019255 Tue Jul 20 13:39:34 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jaxb-runtime-2.3.5.jar
 72008 Tue Jul 20 13:39:08 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/txw2-2.3.5.jar
 29807 Thu Mar 18 15:25:56 CET 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.12.jar
 68453 Thu Feb 20 18:37:08 CET 2020 BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.activation-1.2.2.jar
375623 Fri Sep 17 09:20:56 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-jpa-2.5.5.jar
1260499 Fri Sep 17 09:19:30 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar
204085 Wed Sep 15 07:22:22 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-orm-5.3.10.jar
1267911 Wed Sep 15 07:22:10 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-context-5.3.10.jar
333421 Wed Sep 15 07:22:10 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-tx-5.3.10.jar
696648 Wed Sep 15 07:22:04 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-beans-5.3.10.jar
 41513 Tue Jul 20 13:56:20 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.32.jar
 47229 Wed Sep 15 07:22:24 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-aspects-5.3.10.jar
1392938 Thu Sep 23 07:11:26 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-2.5.5.jar
1564860 Thu Sep 23 07:10:20 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.5.jar
292027 Fri Sep 10 00:27:02 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.2.6.jar
472431 Fri Sep 10 00:15:50 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/logback-core-1.2.6.jar
 17762 Sat Mar 06 22:13:24 CET 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-to-slf4j-2.14.1.jar
300365 Sat Mar 06 22:11:34 CET 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.14.1.jar
  4589 Tue Jul 20 13:55:30 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.32.jar
 25058 Fri Aug 02 11:08:52 CEST 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar
326914 Mon Feb 22 05:55:56 CET 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/snakeyaml-1.28.jar
1515991 Fri Aug 27 00:33:48 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-databind-2.12.5.jar
 75704 Thu Aug 26 23:31:22 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-annotations-2.12.5.jar
365536 Thu Aug 26 23:57:50 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.12.5.jar
 34438 Fri Aug 27 01:10:42 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.12.5.jar
120362 Fri Aug 27 01:10:24 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.12.5.jar
  9440 Fri Aug 27 01:10:34 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.12.5.jar
3429357 Mon Sep 06 23:09:00 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.53.jar
255802 Mon Sep 06 23:09:00 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.53.jar
277386 Mon Sep 06 23:09:00 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.53.jar
1633568 Wed Sep 15 07:22:16 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-web-5.3.10.jar
1027620 Wed Sep 15 07:22:26 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-5.3.10.jar
288281 Wed Sep 15 07:22:04 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-expression-5.3.10.jar
 93107 Tue Dec 19 16:23:24 CET 2017 BOOT-INF/lib/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
2303679 Mon Oct 14 09:19:50 CEST 2019 BOOT-INF/lib/h2-1.4.200.jar
115638 Mon Jan 27 09:34:38 CET 2020 BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar
 46613 Thu Feb 20 18:37:30 CET 2020 BOOT-INF/lib/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.2.jar
1479606 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-core-5.3.10.jar
 24436 Wed Sep 15 07:21:48 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-jcl-5.3.10.jar
 29277 Fri Feb 01 00:00:00 CET 1980 BOOT-INF/lib/spring-boot-jarmode-layertools-2.5.5.jar
  2403 Fri Oct 01 09:00:00 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/classpath.idx
   212 Fri Oct 01 09:00:00 CEST 2021 BOOT-INF/layers.idx
```

**Edit 2** (closer to the resolution)
As Stephen suggested, the internal structure of the generated jar file seems wrong. I crafted an alternative jar file with the paths that don't start with BOOT-INF/classes, and the user.manager service compiles and runs just fine.
Now the question is: how do I instruct spring boot to either generate the correct structure or to "see" the classes?

Comment: Please show the pom.xml for user.manager and the output of running `mvn clean package` for that project.

Comment: I was a bit irritated on the period in `device.manager`, looked into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12013735/best-practices-in-naming-conventions-on-maven-artifactid-is-there-restriction - Not forbidden it seems,

Comment: `-` as a separator is more idiomatic

Comment: @tgdavies I added the data you asked, thank you!

Comment: @JoopEggen To be honest, originally I had usermngt, but then looking around for other tutorials and projects I saw a multimodule project where the modules were named aaa.bbb.ccc and I wanted to try whether or not my naming convention was somehow erroneous and causing the error...

Comment: Please add the output of `jar -tvf /mnt/c/Users/sanvegeta/.m2/repository/com/pippo/device.manager/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/device.manager-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: @tgdavies added also the output of the jar -tvf, thanks again, mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the wrong dependency.  By my reading of the `jar -tf` output, that looks like a SpringBoot executable JAR file.  The `Device.class` file is there, but its path is not right ... for a normal Java compiler to resolve it:

This:

```
 BOOT-INF/classes/com/pippo/device/manager/data/model/Device.class
```

needs to be this:

```
 com/pippo/device/manager/data/model/Device.class
```

---

I can't find any trace of "com.pippo.*" using Google, so I am guessing that this is a private project.

But if you want use the `com.pippo.device.manager` classes in other modules, you need to modify its POM file to generate a regular JAR, and use *that* as the dependency.

One suggestion would be to refactor the existing `com.pippo` / `device.manager` project into a SpringBoot project and a (new) regular "library" JAR project, with the former depending on the latter.  Put the classes that you want to reuse in `com.pluto` / `project.manager` into the "library" project.

Comment: I just added a `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to its pom.xml, ran a `mvn clean install` but the jar content has still the classes into BOOT-INF: should I do something different?

Comment: Did you push a fresh copy of the JAR your repo?  Did you check the build directory to see if there is another (different) JAR file there now as well?  I am not familiar with how Maven SpringBoot projects are built, so I don't know what the POM will look like, or exactly what you need to change.  But *I am sure* that this is the root cause.

Comment: Mate, you're right on the structure. I crafted another jar with the paths as you suggested, and it builds and run perfectly. Now the problem is how to instruct spring boot to generate the proper jar file